# wpcf7_form_response_output hook unresponsive when wp_footer is called

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

GOAL: Use the `wpcf7_form_response_output` filter to dynamically alter the "Success message" that is shown to user upon successful form submission.

ISSUE: When `wp_footer` is called in footer.php, the filter I have in place will not work - ever. However, when `wp_footer` is disabled/removed, the filter will work. Additionally, I noticed that when `wp_footer` is not active, after submission CF7 wil add the form ID to the URL (i.e., #wpcf7-f2294-p2295-o1). Unfortunately I need `wp_footer` enabled.

MY FILTER CODE:

```
function filter_wpcf7_response_output( $output ){

    $date = date('Ymd');

    if( strpos($output, 'wpcf7-mail-sent-ok') ) {
        var_dump($output);
        echo "in if statement";
        ?>
            <script>
                jQuery(function ($) {
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        var newOutput = "Reference ID:" + <?=$date?> + "-00" + "5"+ ". Thank you for your message. It has been sent.";

                        $('.wpcf7-mail-sent-ok').html(newOutput);
                    });
                });
            </script>
    <? }
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'filter_wpcf7_response_output', 10, 1);
```

ATTEMPTS:

- Tried keying off of event listeners for "mailing send" event.
- Tried "hardcoding" solution via `.on("click", ...)` jQuery method. Ultimately, could not alter html of "success message" because said message is not rendered to DOM, so jQuery cannot locate it.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

- Theme utilized is a custom theme using Twenty Fifteen as model/core
- Cannot share site-specific information as this is for business client

POSSIBLE RESOLUTION:

- One way I was able to have `wp_footer` called in `footer.php` and utilize the above filter is if I disabled CF7 script, using: `add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );`.

Comment: First off... `$content = $submission->get_response();` from contact-form.php line 490.  Meaning the message is in `$content` and not `$output`.  If you disable wp_footer, then ajax will be inactive, which is why you get the contact form id in the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'll review your suggestion and see if that will fix my issue. Thanks again :)